# XMCloud + NextJS 13 AppRouter implementation

Tags: nextjs, xm-cloud

We are implementing a headless solution with XMCloud and NextJS. We noticed that sitecore lab sxa-starter already had an example for next 13, but it does not implement AppRouter yet (App Router | Next.js (nextjs.org))  This is a valuable feature for us so we're planning to ask if:

- Someone has a NextJS + XMCloud front-end app with AppRouter example.
- Does Sitecore have any pre-release version of the sxastarter kit for this.
- Does AppRouter included in Sitecore development plan, and if yes, what's the timeline for this.

Thanks

Comment: If you check the Sitecore's official GitHub repository for [FEASS](https://github.com/Sitecore/feaas-nextjs-example) which is a feature of Xmcloud, it uses Nextjs App directory. As app directory is still an experimental feature, so I think after a stable release you might see Sitecore adding full support for it.

Comment: App router has been one of the goals but still under investigation. You can follow for updates https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/discussions/1498